# How to call a specific item in a list subject to another list

Tags: python

I'm just a beginner for python and i wanted to challenge myself so i created a database as a list containing id,password lists such as:

```
database =[['hosni', '66741'], ['merdali', 'mkemal'], ['ahmet', '123'], ['ahmethan', '6669']]
```

I'd like to know  an id's index number in the database, so i tried this:

```
for i in range(len(database)):
  if database[i].index('merdali')==0:
    print(i)
```

However i get this:  `error:ValueError: 'merdali' is not in list`
The point is that should not the program run the entire lists independently and check whether the condition is satisfied or not, if so, print the "i" value I demand?
if the code had worked properly, i would have written the following to access to the password:

```
database[1][1]=='mkemal'
```

thank you for your helps already!

Comment: Why can't you simply check if the username is equal to the first element, i.e. `if database[i][0] == 'merdali':`?

Comment: Ah, it's painful to see how simply it was. Thank you sir!

Comment: The first item in the loop is `['hosni', '66741']`, and `'merdali'` is not a member of that list.  It is an error to call `.index()` with a value that is not a member of the list.

Comment: All good. By the way using indices and `range` is **not** the Pythonic method to iterate over a list. Use `for username, password in database:` and then simply do a `if username == 'merdali`:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to separate out the ids and then use `.index()` on the newly created list

```
[item[0] for item in database].index("merdali")
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow your structure while you get to more advanced subjects,

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate(database):
...   if x[0] == 'merdali':
...     print(i)
...     break
...
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as a `next()` comprehension:

```
index = next(l[1] for l in database if l[0] == "hosni")
```

By the way, a dictionary is a way more suitable choice for your database.